# How to evenly spread butter in each square of a waffle?

Tags: butter, waffle

We made large Belgian-style waffles tonight and I found it incredibly difficult to evenly spread the butter in each square. In fact, it was so time consuming, by the time I was done, the waffle was barely hot :(

As a second attempt, I cut a tablespoon of butter into 16 tiny cubes and let each cube melt in the waffle butter receptacles. This was slightly more effective but it got butter all over my fingers in the process :(

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Melt the butter and brush it on with a pastry brush.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ That comment deserves to be an answer, IMO.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Its too short, and I cannot think of what to add :-)   Thanks, though.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ IMO, yours is a to the point answer. I don;t think every answer needs to be like an essay, anyways it is your call.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Well, I tried it, and the answer went in, although I was accused of not being a human ;-)  There is a requirement built into the system that answers exceed a certain number of characters--I didn't think this was long enough to be accepted.

Comment: For a treat, make chocolate cake batter (a bit thick), and then cover the "waffle" with some glazing :) not diet food

Answer (score 22):

Melt the butter and brush it on with a pastry brush.

Comment: I don't think the brush matters--before I had a pastry brush, I would use a bunch of paper towels folded up.   My personal favorite is the silicone type, like this one:  http://www.amazon.com/OXO-Grips-Silicone-Pastry-Brush/dp/B000JPSI8C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1357633067&sr=8-1&keywords=pastry+brush+silicone

Comment: Melted butter will not make it any softer than butter spread on to the waffle and melting.

Comment: got your point. :) Or we can simply dip the waffle in the melted butter to get it covered with butter on both sides?

Comment: Sure, ja, you betcha.  I almost suggested dipping it lobster style into melted butter, but decided that was too silly, and people might not get that it was a joke :-)  Of course, dipping the whole waffle might be *too much* butter.

Comment: I don't even know what is a waffle, BTW, I am just assuming that it might be a variety of chips. :) :eek:

Comment: Its a kind of fried batter-based breakfast food, cooked in an appliance called a waffle iron.   The batter is usually richer in butter than US-type pancakes, but otherwise quite similar.   Google it and you will see many pictures of the unique appearance.

Comment: Thanks, I googled it after posting that comment, indeed buttering it by hand can be time consuming since it doesn't have an plane surface. I haven't seen and eaten that waffle by now. :)

Comment: Waffles typically have more egg content, no/less sugar added, and much thicker batter than "pancakes"

Comment: If you have a high-heat pastry brush, it also works to butter the waffle iron as you're making them ... and then you use the rest of the melted butter for serving.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ damn you... There is no such thing as "too much butter."

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend cutting super thin slices of butter (cut from a US "stick of butter") and draping them over each "waffle butter receptacle" so that the butter not only melts into the craters but also on the raised edges.

**Maximum yet even butter coverage.**

Answer (score 6):

I've always used a butter spread and simply tilted the knife at a roughly 45 degree angle while scraping across the waffle.  It takes about 10-30 seconds to get about 80-90% of the holes.  Although the butter is not usually perfectly centered in the hole (walled up on the side) it quickly melts and has been good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

Melt a small amount of butter in a large frying pan over medium / low medium.  When melted, put the waffle in the pan and lightly toast.  Your waffle will be evenly coated, warm and even crispier.  Be careful not to burn your butter or waffle. We use this sinful method to make butter buns more buttery. If doing more than one, you might have to clean the pan.  Definitely decadent.

Answer (score 2):

I combined butter and syrup and warmed it. Best of both - melted butter and warm syrup.